# Refreshing Angular component

Tags: angular

I have a search component which is a popup on my home page. After opening the popup and then clicking the search button I call this service below called searchMc. This is the search component.

```
  import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {McService} from '../../shared/services/mc-service';
import {SearchModel, SearchResultModel, WebSearchModel} from './search-model';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {CommunicationService} from '../../shared/services/communication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.less'],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() search: boolean;
  @Output() searchChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  storiesAndMedia: boolean;
  stories: boolean;
  media: boolean;
  loader: boolean;
  result: any;

  searchModelData = new SearchModel();
  searchResultResponse = new SearchResultModel();


  constructor(private mcService: McService, private router: Router, private cs: CommunicationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSearch();
  }


  getSearch() {
    this.mcService.getSearch()
      .subscribe((response) => {
          this.searchModelData = response;
          this.searchModelData.searchModel = new WebSearchModel();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  selectMedia(index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        this.searchModelData.searchModel.images = !this.searchModelData.searchModel.images;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.searchModelData.searchModel.video = !this.searchModelData.searchModel.video;
        break;
      case 3:
        this.searchModelData.searchModel.document = !this.searchModelData.searchModel.document;
        break;
      case 4:
        this.searchModelData.searchModel.audio = !this.searchModelData.searchModel.audio;
        break;
    }
  }

  customChecked(custom) {
    custom.marked = !custom.marked;
    const index1 = this.searchModelData.searchModel.customCategoryIds.indexOf(custom);
    if (custom.marked) {
      this.searchModelData.searchModel.customCategoryIds.push(custom.id);
    }
    else {
      this.searchModelData.searchModel.customCategoryIds.splice(index1, 1);
    }
  }

  categoryChecked(category) {
    category.checked = !category.checked;
    const index2 = this.searchModelData.searchModel.mainCategoryIds.indexOf(category);
    if (category.checked) {
      this.searchModelData.searchModel.mainCategoryIds.push(category.id);
    }
    else {
      this.searchModelData.searchModel.mainCategoryIds.splice(index2, 1);
    }
  }

  all() {
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.images = true;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.video = true;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.document = true;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.audio = true;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.media = !this.searchModelData.searchModel.media;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.stories = !this.searchModelData.searchModel.stories;
    this.storiesAndMedia = !this.storiesAndMedia;
    this.stories = false;
    this.media = false;
  }

  mediaActive() {
    this.storiesAndMedia = false;
    this.media = !this.media;
    this.stories = false;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.media = true;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.stories = false;
  }

  storiesActive() {
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.images = false;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.video = false;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.document = false;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.audio = false;
    this.storiesAndMedia = false;
    this.stories = !this.stories;
    this.media = false;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.media = false;
    this.searchModelData.searchModel.stories = true;
  }


  brandChecked(brand) {
    brand.checked = !brand.checked;
    const index = this.searchModelData.searchModel.subClientIds.indexOf(brand);
    if (brand.checked) {
      this.searchModelData.searchModel.subClientIds.push(brand.id);
    }
    else {
      this.searchModelData.searchModel.subClientIds.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  searchMc() {
    this.loader = true;
    this.closeSearch();
    this.mcService.searchMc(this.searchModelData.searchModel)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          localStorage.clear();
          this.searchResultResponse = response;
          localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(this.searchResultResponse));
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/results');
          this.loader = false;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

  }

  closeSearch() {
    this.searchChange.emit(false);
  }
}
```

This is the result Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {McService} from '../../shared/services/mc-service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {CommunicationService} from '../../shared/services/communication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.less']
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  result: any;
  autoplay: boolean;
  mediaId: number;
  popup: boolean;
  loader: boolean;
  storyId: number;

  constructor(private mcService: McService, private router: Router, private cs: CommunicationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    if (localStorage.getItem('result') != null) {
      this.result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('result'));
    }
  }

  readMore(id) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    sessionStorage.setItem('storyId', JSON.stringify(id));
    this.mcService.addViewToNews(id)
      .subscribe((response) => {

        },
        (error2 => {
          console.log(error2);
        }));
    this.router.navigate(['/newsdetail/' + id]);
  }

  openDropdown(id) {
    for (const x of this.result.stories) {
      if (x.storyId === id) {
        x.dropdown = !x.dropdown;
      }
    }
  }


  openMediaPopup(id) {
    this.autoplay = false;
    this.mediaId = id;
    this.popup = true;
    this.mcService.addViewToMedia(id);
  }

  openMediaPopupAutplay(id) {
    this.autoplay = true;
    this.mediaId = id;
    this.popup = true;
    this.mcService.addViewToMedia(id);
  }
}
```

Then I get redirected to `/results`. But I have a problem. When I am on  that same route `/results` if I click on search popup, then search button which calls the service again, the `/results` page doesn't refresh the content, because I am on that same route and since I am sending the response of the search through localstorage (I did this because I didn't know any other way) all of the results are stored on localstorage but the results page doesn't get the new content it stays the same. Is there a way to refresh the page every time I click Search button but without using localstorage. I've tried some kind of a communication service using `Subject` it was buggy didn't really work.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without more details we can't help you

Comment: Maybe you should consider a state management tool like ngrx(Redux). Your service will update state and your components will be selecting state.

Comment: If you say on the same page not have to navigate again. Angular works with a binding model so if `this.data = 0;` template show 0. If `this.data = 1` template show 1. Same goes with localstorage you store it and you reload it with `getItem()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another example(!), maybe not the equivalent solution according to the type of your object. It's just supposed to show you that your service can handle every type of object.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

    private searchItem: BehaviorSubject< SearchResultResponse > = new BehaviorSubject(any);

    constructor() { }

    getSearchItem(): Observable<any> {
       return this.searchItem.asObservable();
    }

    getSearchItemValue(): SearchResultResponse {
       return this.searchItem.getValue();
    }

    setSearchItem(val: any) {
        this.searchItem.next(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am defining the searchResultResponse in my SearchComponent searchResultResponse = new SearchResultModel(); so i cant add it in the service like that. Also, you wrote  this.storageService.getSearchTerm().subscribe(term => {
        this.result = term; 
    }); in the example above, is it supposed to say getSearchItem(), it still doesnt work, i just get an empty string.

Comment: With this new example im getting undefined

Comment: But this should happen only at the beginning as the initial value is undefined. btw You can use 'any' instead of a concrete object inside the service!

Comment: I understand but the setSearchItem() works when i check inside the developer console but the getSearchItem() doesnt it returns undefined instead.

Comment: In my second example I replaced everything with 'any' right now. Does your Service look the same?

Comment: I've changed the service abit it looks like this now:                     
 private searchItem: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(new SearchModel()); The rest is the same when compared with your second example, also ive removed the stringify inside the search components search service.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i was confused abit at the start but i didnt really give you much to work with. Anyways it works now, and it refreshes the page even if im on it at the time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a service. Here is an example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

    private searchItem: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

    constructor() { }

    getSearchItem(): Observable<string> {
        return this.searchItem.asObservable();
    }

    getSearchItemValue(): string {
        return this.searchItem.getValue();
    }

    setSearchItem(val: string) {
        this.searchItem.next(val);
    }
}
```

In your ResultComponent subscribe to this service and have your local variable that provides the value updated whenever the value inside the service changes.

Attention! The value can be whatever you want. It has not strictly to be a string. This is just for the example.

```
import {StorageService} from 'storage.service.ts';

constructor(
 private storageService: StorageService
){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Update with every change
    this.storageService.getSearchTerm().subscribe(term => {
        this.result = term; 
    });
}
```

And your SearchComponent has to set the value to the StorageSevice after each search instead of putting it to the local storage

```
import {StorageService} from 'storage.service.ts';

constructor(
 private storageService: StorageService
){}


this.mcService.searchMc(this.searchModelData.searchModel)
  .subscribe((response) => {
      this.searchResultResponse = response;

     this.storageService.setSearchItem(JSON.stringify(this.searchResultResponse));

      this.router.navigateByUrl('/results');
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: The search model i am using doesnt send only a string in search it sends an object. After getting the response in results component the result is undefined and the term is " "

Comment: I edited my answer. The value you store inside the service can be of every type you want. Just store the SearchResultResponse-Object directly in it. For this you only have to modify the BehaviorSubject and the corresponding signature of the getters and setters. And you can also put as much fields as you need to this service. You only have to add the additional getters and setters. But the technique will always be the same.

Comment: You only have to know of which type the object is you want to store in the service. Adjust the BehaviorSubject as well as the getters and setters according to this object-type and it'll work.